# Disable RabbitMQ Http Auth (Make RabbitMQ Publicly Accessible)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I want to allow everyone to write to a queue via http. The route is host.com/api/exchanges/vhost/name/publish, however it requires basic auth headers to be passed for the POST request.

Is there a way to fully disable any authentication for writing to a queue via http?

Comment: What about security?

Comment: Security doesn't matter for now